# iOS Genuine Old-School Threaded Mail Reader

Tags: ios, email

Back in the day...

Mail threads were built on In-Reply-To:, References: and Message-ID: headers. The concept was represented in a GUI as a discussion thread, with branches, sub-branches and could even have the subject changed.  The threads were durable, participants could change in a thread and even the subject could change in the thread.

[image: Old-style threads]

Today...

"Conversation Views" have been built by Google, Microsoft and Apple, these are sorted by time, one-dimensional, they ignore the possibility that the list of participants changes over time, and worse, they obfuscate the sender/recipient list.  The built-in Mail client on IOS does a terrible job when somebody replies to a branch of a thread, showing a vertical list of messages and dropping the reader into the middle of it.  Going backward and forward gets you even more lost.  They make matters worse by hiding the time of the emails, the detailed recipient list.  Changes in distribution (e.g., adding a new recipient to bring management attention to something) are hidden under extra touches in the UI.

[image: Threaded Conversation]

This non-representation of the structure of the conversation is so completely useless to me, that I simply cannot read complex discussions on my phone.

I should add that this behaviour of mail clients is deep.  E.g., mail clients typically forward the entire thread in every email, recipient lists are difficult to edit and difficult to access or even see.

The trend seems to be away from managing email in my old way, but instead on search, tagging, priority inboxes, etc, etc.  It's difficult to even look for this kind of capability because the term "Threading" has been redefined.  Even Apple calls this vertical column of a conversation "threading".

Android has k9 mail, last I used Android (in 2013?) it did a good job at this.  Is there any mail client for IOS which supports model #1?   What would you even call this feature?